# Reading lots of data returned by API

Tags: java, android, xml, json

I am reading from an API provided by a company, but the problem is that one of the accounts from which I am getting the data has around 22000 json objects, it reads fine with small amounts of data, i would say up to 8000 records, but then I get issues like the json is not well formatted besides the problem of being able to read the response.

The response comes this way:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://ywers.com">
[{"Name":"Edward", "LastName":"Jones", "Address":"{accepted}"}
,{"Name":"Carlos",  "LastName":"Ramirez", "Address":"{Rejected}"}, ....... 22k more records here]</string>
```

I asked for some help earlier on here for the best way to do this, and i got a response about reading it using the xml parser and then a json parser, i am using GSON.

```
String XML = "<Your XML Response>";
XPathExpression xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance()
                         .newXPath().compile("/*[local-name()='string']");
String json = xpath.evaluate(new InputSource(new StringReader(XML)));
```

and then

```
JSONArray jsonRoot = new JSONArray(json.trim());
System.out.println(jsonRoot.getJSONObject(0).getString("Address")); // {accepted}
```

The problem with this is approach i am having is that it throws errors when reading the XML, it starts reading but after a while it stops with errors like:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractBuilder.java:94)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:219)
at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.CharacterDataImpl.appendData(CharacterDataImpl.java:43)
......
```

I would appreciate any advise on how to proceed with this, I am kind of new to android.

Comment: Find whomever wrapped a JSON array of 22k elements in XML (and as a bonus in *one element*), and shoot them. You're going to have a very hard time dealing with that.

Comment: ranged query API should be provide.

Comment: I know... what a pain...

Comment: Agree with @BrianRoach. Whoever designed the Api should implement indexes and limits. Even if you don't get an OutOfMemoryError, your going to have problems.

Comment: in this specific case, is it possible to use regular expression to parse the attributes, since the json structure here is simple.

Comment: Well in reality, the json comes with address 1, address 2, and a bunch others, this is not the only issue, some of the data is coming like with html and messes up the call too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know who would wrap 22k objects inside a xml string, but apparently someone is doing that. From my experience, your out of memory is because the you try to convert all the response to string but the response is too big to be handled. I recommend you to stream the JSON data. You can do stream the JSON data from the inputstream response that you get from the your HTTP post, but you need to skip the XML part by creating another input stream from the original response input stream and skip the XML part

Before I use the streaming API from google GSON I also got OOM error because the JSON data I got is very big data (many images and sounds in Base64 encoding) but with GSON streaming I can overcome that error because it reads the data per token not all at once. And for alternative you can also use Jackson JSON library I think it also have streaming API and how to use it almost same with my implementation with google GSON. I hope my answer can help you and if you have another question about my answer feel free to ask in the comment :)

Comment: That sounds like a plan, how can i skip that xml if you dont mind me asking.